# Is there an API for a UWP App to Self Uninstall? C#

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a way for a UWP to have a self uninstall function?

Scenario is a LOB UWP app the we want to be uninstalled remotely if user has been marked unauthorized.

Comment: One could still revoke access with authorization tokens (eg. checked in startup with a message if access is revoked), without removal. The user would then likely acquire access again or remove the app themselves. Removing the app doesn’t itself prevent reinstalling, and auto-removing an application might be a confusing (even if possible) user experience.

Comment: That's the currently implementation, but got curious about complete uninstall since it would be the "cleanest"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an API is not currently available. If it were, its home would be the [`StoreContext` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.uninstallstorepackageasync#Windows_Services_Store_StoreContext_UninstallStorePackageAsync_Windows_ApplicationModel_Package_) which currently hosts the ability to uninstall optional packages ("DLCs"), but does not offer the same for the app itself.